# Undefined array key in my mappedBy entity

Tags: php, symfony

I'm lost in my code.

i have a warning from symfony ORM who said "Undefined array key as programmes".
I thinks this come from my entity Formations when i try to use mappedBy="programmes"
But i don't understand why.

i use this documentation for understand my problem but always nothing :/
https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html

I try to show a Formation with programme.
One Formation can have many programme.
programme can have  only one formation.

So the relation is OneToMany for my entity Formations.
When i want to show one formation, i want to show a list in my form with many programme.

How can i solve this.

This is my my code from entity Formation :

```
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Category::class, inversedBy="Formations")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=ProgrammeFormation::class, mappedBy="programmes", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    protected $programmeFormations;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=ObjectifFormation::class, mappedBy="objectifs", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $objectifFormations;
```

this is my code from entity ProgrammeFormation

```
class ProgrammeFormation
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Formations::class, inversedBy="programmeFormations",cascade={"persist","remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")
     * @ORM\Column(nullable=true)
     */
    protected $programmes;
```

this is my controlleur

```
 public function edit(Formations $formation, Request $request, $id, FormationsRepository $repo,EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
       
        $ProgrammesCollection = new ArrayCollection();
        $form = $this->createForm(FormationType::class, $formation);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            foreach ($ProgrammesCollection as $programme) {
                if (false === $formation->getProgrammeFormations()->contains($programme)) {
                    $programme->setProgrammes(null);
                    $this->em->remove($programme);
                    
                }
            }
                    $this->em->flush();
                    $this->addFlash('success', 'Bien modifié avec succès');
                    return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_admin_gestion');
        }

        return $this->render('admin/formation/edit.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }
```

this is my form

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title')
            ->add('Date') //Date de la formation
            ->add('price')
            ->add('category', EntityType::class,[
                'class' => Category::class,
                'choice_label' => 'title'
            ])
            ->add('programmeFormations', CollectionType::class,[
                'entry_type' => ProgrammeType::class,
                'entry_options'=> ['label' => false],
                'allow_add' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'allow_delete' => true,
            ])
            ->add('objectifFormations', CollectionType::class,[
                'entry_type' => ObjectifType::class,
                'entry_options'=> ['label' => false],
                'allow_add' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'allow_delete' => true, 
            ])
            ->add('duration') //Durée
            ->add('forWho')
            ->add('prerequisite')
            ->add('location')
        ;
    }
```

this is the error
[image]

and the détail :

[image]

and all message errors:
[image]

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Show us ALL the error message and the file and line number should be in the error message

Comment: i edit my post, don't hesitate to answer if you need more information, thanks !

Comment: Use EntityType on programmeFormation, define class na choise_label options

Comment: Are you sur about this ? Because i want to show my propriety name from my programmeFormation entity who is a collection of my Formation entity.

Comment: i miss to link my entity programmeFormation with my entity Formation. problem is solve

Comment: @Chlem if you solved your problem - can you provide answer to your own question please ? :-) thank you